# How come there is '\0' at the end of the string while nobody put it there?

Tags: c, string

I was trying to implement `strcat` by myself, It seems to work but I don't understand how come  `p` has `'\0'` at its end? it didn't copy it from b and it shouldn't be there without putting it. Any explanation? The output is "yesMichaelJudy".

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include<conio.h>


char* strcat1( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    register char  *p = s1;

    while ( *p )
          ++p;

    while (*s2){

        *p=*s2;
        ++p;
        ++s2;

    }

    if (*p=='\0') printf("yes");
    ++p;
    p='\0';

    return s1;
}


int main(){

    char* a;
    char* b;

    char* result;
    result=(char *)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    a=(char *) calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    b=(char *) calloc(20,sizeof(char));
     strcpy (a,"Michael");
    strcpy (b,"Judy");
    result=strcat1(a,b);

    printf(result);

    getch();
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: C needs to know when it hit the end of string.

Comment: Because it's a C "string", which is a fictitious object, simulated by placing a "null" (zero byte) in the last character location of a character array.  This is known as the "null-terminated string".

Comment: (What do you think it is you're testing when you say `while ( *p )`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're allocating the space larger than it needs to be and you're using calloc() which by definition clears all the characters to zero; therefore the extra characters at the end are zero.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy` copies the NUL character at the end of a string. Even if it didn't, you're using `calloc` to allocate your `a` and `b`, and `calloc` allocates *and zeros* the memory. Since you're allocating more space than you use (allocating 20 bytes, using 4 for `Judy` and 7 for `Michael`) you have some zero bytes after the strings anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
p='\0';
```

That's nonsense. It does nothing useful. It will also generate at least a compiler warning if not an error. The code should be

```
*p='\0';
```

Which is what puts \0 at the end of the string.

Comment: It's not useful, but it's not an error. `'\0'`, like any integer constant expression with a value of zero, is a null pointer constant. `p = '\0';` is an obfuscated equivalent of `p = NULL;`. Since `p` ceases to exist immediately thereafter, it has no net effect.

Answer (score 0):

calloc zero initializes ( ie fills it with NUL or '\0') the allocated buffer.

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. The null *character* is commonly referred to as `NUL`, but `0` or `'\0'` is a more obvious way to refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

strcpy() null-terminates the string. But even if it didn't, calloc() puts it there. calloc() zeroes out the allocated memory. As soon as you allocated the memory, a and b are just a bunch of string-terminators.

Answer (score 0):

`p` in your `strcat1` points into the array passed through parameter `s1`. And parameter `s1` corresponds to argument `a` in `main`. The content of array `a` in main is filled with data by `strcpy (a,"Michael")`. This is what put that `'\0'` at the end of that data. `strcpy` did that. (You can also say that that `'\0'` came from `"Michael"` since `"Michael"` also has a `'\0'` at the end, even if it is not specified explicitly).